# Rug plot in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a built-in way in pgfplots to make rug plots? The rug refers to the tick marks on the inside of the axis. There is one tick mark per datapoint represented in the plot.

Like  this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [pydata.org](https://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/distributions_10_0.png))</sub>

or even this:

[image]

?

I don't know if its just my not reading the manual correctly, or if it isn't there.

Thanks

.

edit:
Here is some histogram data I made up. I've added the code I think should make the ticks: [Plotting a 2D gaussian sample](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107778/plotting-a-2d-gaussian-sample/107784#107784) and I've changed the fill opacity to see if that helped, which it didn't.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={Count},
    axis lines = left,
    every outer x axis line/.append style= {-},
    every outer y axis line/.append style= {-},    
    xmin=-3, xmax=3,
    ybar=0pt, bar width=1,
   xtick=data, 
    xticklabel=\empty,
    extra x ticks={-3,...,3},
    every extra x tick/.style={
        tick align=outside,
        xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}
    },
]
\addplot[
black, 
fill=red,
  fill opacity=0.02,
hist={bins=12},
] 
    table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
-0.3662\\ 0.8510\\ -0.6391\\ -1.8496\\ 1.3160\\ -0.3006\\ -0.1287\\ 0.9324\\ 0.4970\\ -2.1474\\
0.0184\\ 0.2656\\ -0.4691\\ 0.4598\\ -0.3074\\ -0.9293\\ 0.6791\\ -0.9676\\ -0.5833\\ 2.7928\\
0.4582\\ 0.7967\\ 0.8900\\ -0.9640\\ 0.1757\\ -0.8618\\ 0.8212\\ 0.0399\\ 0.9268\\ -0.5465\\
1.4702\\ -2.0286\\ 0.4796\\ -1.3354\\ -1.8256\\ -0.9834\\ 0.5041\\ -0.5414\\ 1.1379\\ 1.2965\\
0.1740\\ 0.4718\\ 0.9251\\ -0.2399\\ 0.0854\\ -2.7529\\ -0.1187\\ 0.8095\\ -0.3766\\ 0.8983\\};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you didn't provide some code that we can play with, here only a comment on what you could do: You could do this indirectly creating a dummy data set including all data and plotting it (invisible) and adding `xtick=data` to the `axis` option. Then you would get a tick at every data point (of course only in one color). But because you don't want to have each of the ticks labeled, you should also add `xticklabels={}` to the axis options. To then have the normal axis ticks and labels you can use the `extra x ticks`. The same could be done for the y-axis.

Comment: I also have another idea in mind, but for that it would be nice to have some code to play with. I don't want to invest time to first create some dummy plot and you later say: "But I need ..." or "Could you also do it for ...". So please provide some code (and data) that is close to what you really need.

Comment: Something similar can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107784/2552

Comment: @Jake Yes, it does look like what I'm after. The code works at my end, but adding the appropriate lines to my code doesn't seem to work. Maybe it's something to do with plot order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "problem" is that you plot a histogram only and thus you only get the `xtick`s for them. To show the `xtick`s for your data, you have to draw them also/first.

For more details and improvements please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat' level or higher to use the "advanced" positioning
    % of the axis labels
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={Count},
        axis lines=left,
        every outer x axis line/.append style={-},
        every outer y axis line/.append style={-},
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=3,
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=1,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel=\empty,
        extra x ticks={-3,...,3},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % to distinguish between the ticks drawn for the labels and the one
        % to mark data points, use different styles for them, e.g.
        tick align=inside,
        xtick style={
            draw=red,
        },
        extra x tick style={
            tick align=outside,
            xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick},
            xtick style={
                draw=black!50,
            },
        },
        % draw axis on top of the plots, so they are not "overdrawn"
        axis on top,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]

    % plot the raw data (without the `hist') to produce the ticks
    % (`xtick=data' only accounts for the *first* plot)
    \addplot [
        draw=none,
    ] table [row sep=\\,y expr=0] {
        data\\
        -0.3662\\ 0.8510\\ -0.6391\\ -1.8496\\ 1.3160\\ -0.3006\\ -0.1287\\ 0.9324\\ 0.4970\\ -2.1474\\
        0.0184\\ 0.2656\\ -0.4691\\ 0.4598\\ -0.3074\\ -0.9293\\ 0.6791\\ -0.9676\\ -0.5833\\ 2.7928\\
        0.4582\\ 0.7967\\ 0.8900\\ -0.9640\\ 0.1757\\ -0.8618\\ 0.8212\\ 0.0399\\ 0.9268\\ -0.5465\\
        1.4702\\ -2.0286\\ 0.4796\\ -1.3354\\ -1.8256\\ -0.9834\\ 0.5041\\ -0.5414\\ 1.1379\\ 1.2965\\
        0.1740\\ 0.4718\\ 0.9251\\ -0.2399\\ 0.0854\\ -2.7529\\ -0.1187\\ 0.8095\\ -0.3766\\ 0.8983\\
    };
    % then plot the hist
    \addplot[
        draw=black,
        fill=red,
        fill opacity=0.2,
        hist={bins=12},
    ] table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        -0.3662\\ 0.8510\\ -0.6391\\ -1.8496\\ 1.3160\\ -0.3006\\ -0.1287\\ 0.9324\\ 0.4970\\ -2.1474\\
        0.0184\\ 0.2656\\ -0.4691\\ 0.4598\\ -0.3074\\ -0.9293\\ 0.6791\\ -0.9676\\ -0.5833\\ 2.7928\\
        0.4582\\ 0.7967\\ 0.8900\\ -0.9640\\ 0.1757\\ -0.8618\\ 0.8212\\ 0.0399\\ 0.9268\\ -0.5465\\
        1.4702\\ -2.0286\\ 0.4796\\ -1.3354\\ -1.8256\\ -0.9834\\ 0.5041\\ -0.5414\\ 1.1379\\ 1.2965\\
        0.1740\\ 0.4718\\ 0.9251\\ -0.2399\\ 0.0854\\ -2.7529\\ -0.1187\\ 0.8095\\ -0.3766\\ 0.8983\\
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]